# Setting variables in bash

Tags: bash

I am setting the value for `iq` in a bash script, but the value of `iq` is not being displayed.

```
local divisor=5 iq=$divisor
echo $divisor $iq
```

Comment: Are you using `local` in function or on its own?  On its own, don't use it and instead make the variables on 2 separate lines starting with `divisor=5`.

Comment: It is being set up inside a function.

Comment: Is setting variables on a single line not good?  Have been doing `local jr=$1 jg=$2 jb=$3 rc="\e[0m"` which seemed to work as expected.

Comment: The difference is *when* they are evaluated; afaik the bash interpreter makes a single pass over each complete statement, so at the point that `ip=$divisor` is parsed, `$divisor` is empty. You can see the same behavior without invoking functions e.g. compare `bash -xc 'declare divisor=5 ip=$divisor'` versus `bash -xc 'declare divisor=5; ip=$divisor'`

Comment: Would there be a good argument for bash to change such behaviour and allow variables to take values, rather than using a newline?